# What is the correct way to push a View Controller after a selection from a menu?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, menu, storyboard, segue

In my app I have a "home" screen from which I can present a hamburger menu (coded as a modal transition in Storyboard).
The menu is a UITableView where a user will select a row. The menu has a delegate method which calls the following function in the presenting screen (my "home" screen)

```
// Menu delegate method
func menuDidExit(menuVC:MenuVC) {
    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {
        // After dismissal of menu, call the chosen option
        if let selectedOption = menuVC.menuSelection {
            self.performSegueWithIdentifier(menuVC.menuSelection?.rawValue, sender: self)
        }
    })
}
```

This function will both dismiss the menu view controller, and then (once that transition is complete), present a second view controller based upon the chosen menu option, using the "performSegueWithIdentifier" command.

The issue that I have is that while the menu dismiss works fine (the menu slides off screen gracefully) - there is no animation for the presentation of the next view controller - it simply appears on screen after the menu has been dismissed.

I can call the desired view controller via a button/segue, and all works well, however when it is part of the completion block above it fails to animate the transition. This leads me to believe that there is something fundamentally wrong with my approach - hence the question, what is the correct way to push a second view controller after handling the dismissal of the first.

Many thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    self.dismiss(animated: true) { 
        //dismiss your menu here
    }
}
```

Hope it can help you.
Please let me know if it not work.
Thanks